# I got the "image-annotator::Bad image data.: Image processing error!" from Google Cloud Vision

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call Google Cloud Vision from a PHP Script. And also, I want to get the image data from a Web page and try to send image data from JavaScript to PHP script.

But, I got the error message from Google Cloud Vision.

```
{
    "responses": [
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 3,
        "message": "image-annotator::Bad image data.: Image processing error!"
        }
    }]
}
```

This is my javascript code fragment.

```
    var b64 = ImageToBase64(img, "image/jpeg");
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ocr.php",
        data: "data=" + b64,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        // Method when calling ocr.php was successed. 
        success: function(data, dataType)
        {
            // Show the data
            console.log(data);
            $("#source_text").html(data);
            var text = "It is snow today";
            translateText(text);
        },
        // Method when calling ocr.php was failed.
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Display error message.
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });

function ImageToBase64(img, mime_type) {
    // New Canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width  = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    // Draw Image
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // To Base64
    return canvas.toDataURL(mime_type);
}
```

And my PHP script is below.

```
$api_key = "my-api-key" ;

$image_data = $_POST["data"];
$image = base64_decode($image_data);

// Feature Type
$feature = "TEXT_DETECTION";

$param = array("requests" => array());
// $item["image"] = array("content" => base64_encode($image));
$item["image"] = array("content" => $image_data);
$item["features"] = array(array("type" => $feature, "maxResults" => 1));
$param["requests"][] = $item;

$json = json_encode($param);

$curl = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" . $api_key);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$res1 = curl_exec($curl);
$res2 = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$json = substr($res1, $res2["header_size"]);
$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json;
```

I guess image processing must be wrong. But I have no idea what should I do about this. 
Would you give me an advice?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring out what your problem was? I am coming across the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google PHP API-Client-Library with a ServiceAccount and OAuth 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-encode the image on PHP side:

```
    // re-encode image
    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imageData);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
```